# Angular2, How to use object from one component to another component?

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

I am using two various component,

one is sample.ts, another one is testing.ts

```
export class TestComponent {
 save(){
  console.log('this is a testing file')
  }
}
```

Is this possibe to use save() in sample.ts?? which is in testing.ts
    ->save()??

If this possible means, anyone plz help me...

Comment: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html

Comment: What is your component hierarchy? Which component is parent and which is child?

Comment: sample.ts is parent, testing.ts is a child

Answer (score 0):

I'd put this function in a shared service and make it Injectable and use it every where .

```
  @Injectable()

  export class MyService{

   public save(){

     console.log('this is a testing file')

   }
}
```

In your components :

```
  constructor(private myService:MyService){

    // use it however you want
    myService.save();

  }
```

And if you don't want to do this , you need to seperately export that function only :

```
export function save() {

  console.log('this is a testing file')

}
```

EDIT :

If you want to keep the state of this service over all your components , you need to provide it at your top level app .

The service will behave as a singleton object and all the child component will use it and it'll save the state .

So go to your app.ts ( probably) and provide the service and delete it from any child components providers list.

Comment: If I add "Public" in my save() means, it will be show error. angular2-polyfills.js:390 Error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token .(…) :(

Comment: My mistake , save should be a function not a class !:)

Comment: Yes, You are right, i Updated it. I reached save from one component to another. but i can't get value. kindly see my post plz...

Comment: Its working fine when i'm using same component.but I didn't get value, when i'm coming from another component. I got only
empty alert, which is i mentioned in the below posted answer.

Comment: @Injectable()  export class MyService{  public save(){  var name = this.name;  alert('my name is'+name ); } } Its working fine when i'm using same component. but I didn't get value, when i'm coming from another component. I got only empty alert. (i.e) constructor(private myService:MyService){ this.myService.save();  } How can i solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can make your method public: `public save() { ... }` then import your TestComponent in your SampleComponent, create an instance of TestComponent and call `let tc = new TestComponent(); tc.save();`

Comment: I got a followng error,  angular2-polyfills.js:390 Error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token .(…)